# In "He is a pool shark," what field is he good at?

Tags: meaning

I have got some versions of my guesses:

1. He is a good swimmer.
2. He is an expert in playing billards.
3. He is a pro at gambling.

*Pool* can mean a lot of things. So can *shark*. Which one is the most correct or proper explanation?

Comment: I was really surprised to see this term in so [few dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=pool+shark&ls=a). The second definition at Urban Dictionary actually explains it rather well: "One whose goal is to con money out of others by using a combination of deception, talent, and straight coercion, combined with the game of billiards, to take advantage of susceptible players."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They play the game of [***pool***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28cue_sports%29) :

> Pool, also more formally known as pocket billiards (mostly in North America) or pool billiards[1] (mostly in Europe and Australia), is the family of cue sports and games played on a pool table having six receptacles called pockets along the rails, into which balls are deposited as the main goal of play. Popular versions include eight-ball and nine-ball.

And [***shark***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cue_sports_terms#shark) means

> Also pool shark, poolshark (US); sharp, pool sharp (British)
>       1.  Verb: To perform some act or make some utterance with the intent to distract,   irritate or intimidate the opponent so that they do not perform well, miss a shot, etc.[6] Most league and tournament rules forbid blatant sharking, as a form of unsportsmanlike conduct, but it is very common in bar pool.
>       2.  Noun: Another term for [hustler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hustling).[6]
>       3.  Noun: A very good player. This usage is common among non-players who often intend it as a compliment and are not aware of its derogatory senses (above)

Skill alone is not enough be labeled a *pool shark*, the intent to hustle you is also required.